# TextView background color mixed with parent element background color

Tags: android, xml

I have a layout with a TextView like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/contentColorBackground"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/contentColorBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Anecdote_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Click Me"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/categories_button"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

It uses that drawable as a background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/anecdoteBorderLine" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/anecdoteStartTopColor" android:endColor="@color/anecdoteEndBottomColor"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#f22121" />
            <solid android:color="#b5ffaf10"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/anecdoteBorderLine" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/anecdoteStartTopColor" android:endColor="@color/anecdoteEndBottomColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Everything seems ok, but there is a big problem, the background color of Linear Layout apears mixed with the color of the TextView. That's not what i want, i want the TextView to have only the color of the drawable as it's background.
What's the correct way for me to do that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: set the linear layout background color to transparent.

Comment: I think you have a problem with transparency in your textView. The first two signs after the hash tag will define the transparency. You have to change the colors defined with 8 numbers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be how your declaring the color with a slight transparency.

```
<item android:state_focused="true">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#f22121" />
            <solid android:color="#b5ffaf10"/>
     </shape>
</item>
```

if you change this line to

```
<solid android:color="#ffffaf10"/>
```

you should have a solid color as your background.

Comment: You could also leave out the first two "ff" it will have the same effect as a solid color

Comment: This was the problem! i wanted to have soft colors and was using transparency for that... It's solved now!

Answer (score 0):

in your drawable in this line (14 line in the given code):

```
<solid android:color="#b5ffaf10"/>
```

try to remove the two last numbers. normally there ar only 6 numbers after the # for RGB - red, green, blue. If you set for example "#FF0000" it is 100% red or "#00FF00" it is 100% green. the other two numbers, in your case is 10, defines the transparency of the selected color.

Comment: first two numbers define transparency

Comment: It is in ARGB Format

Comment: then remove the b5 instead of the 10